# In Angular2, Angular/Material getting error MdCoreModule not exported

Tags: node.js, angular

I recently inherited a Node.js with Angular 2 project and am trying to get up to speed. There are, obviously, numerous issues I am confronting so I am not sure if there is a direct version problem here, or if I set up something wrong.

I have the following import in a module from an example found here: http://candordeveloper.com/2017/04/25/how-to-create-dynamic-menu-and-page-title-with-angular-material-and-cli/

```
import { //only import the portions you will use to optimize build (MaterialModule to include all is deprecated)
      MdCoreModule,
      MdButtonModule,
      MdCardModule,
      MdIconModule,
      MdMenuModule,
      MdRippleModule,
      MdSidenavModule,
      MdToolbarModule,
      //... add others you need
} from '@angular/material';
```

I used

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

to install the required packages, but am getting "'MdCoreModule' not exported error.

In package.json I have:

```
{
  "name": "Test_Project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

I figure it might be a version issue, but I cannot find any related issues anywhere.

Comment: What is `MdCoreModule`? That is not one of angular's required dependencies. I don't know if it used to be, but it's at least not anymore.

Comment: @JunKang Ah, okay, thank you. This is a pretty old article. Guess I will stop chasing this goose and look for more recent material to familiarize myself with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a copy of the (now deprecated) Material Module that Angular deleted from the official project. [See Here](https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/cf1ece0).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { BidiModule } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { ObserversModule } from '@angular/cdk/observers';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { PlatformModule } from '@angular/cdk/platform';

import { 
  MdAutocompleteModule, 
  MdButtonModule, 
  MdButtonToggleModule, 
  MdCardModule, 
  MdChipsModule, 
  MdCheckboxModule, 
  MdDatepickerModule, 
  MdTableModule, 
  MdDialogModule, 
  MdExpansionModule, 
  MdFormFieldModule, 
  MdGridListModule, 
  MdIconModule, 
  MdInputModule, 
  MdListModule, 
  MdMenuModule, 
  MdPaginatorModule, 
  MdProgressBarModule, 
  MdProgressSpinnerModule, 
  MdRadioModule, 
  MdRippleModule, 
  MdSelectModule, 
  MdSidenavModule, 
  MdSliderModule, 
  MdSlideToggleModule, 
  MdSnackBarModule, 
  MdSortModule, 
  MdStepperModule, 
  MdTabsModule, 
  MdToolbarModule, 
  MdTooltipModule, 
  StyleModule, 
  MdCommonModule 
} from '@angular/material';

const MATERIAL_MODULES = [
  MdAutocompleteModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdButtonToggleModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdChipsModule,
  MdCheckboxModule,
  MdDatepickerModule,
  MdTableModule,
  MdDialogModule,
  MdExpansionModule,
  MdFormFieldModule,
  MdGridListModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdListModule,
  MdMenuModule,
  MdPaginatorModule,
  MdProgressBarModule,
  MdProgressSpinnerModule,
  MdRadioModule,
  MdRippleModule,
  MdSelectModule,
  MdSidenavModule,
  MdSliderModule,
  MdSlideToggleModule,
  MdSnackBarModule,
  MdSortModule,
  MdStepperModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdTooltipModule,
  OverlayModule,
  PortalModule,
  BidiModule,
  StyleModule,
  A11yModule,
  PlatformModule,
  MdCommonModule,
  ObserversModule,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: MATERIAL_MODULES,
  exports: MATERIAL_MODULES,
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

`MdCoreModule`, while I'm not sure if it used to be there, isn't there for their recent versions, definitely so for you since your package.json says you're using beta.11, which is the most current version at this time. I assume yours would work if you simply got rid of `MdCoreModule`.

I can't tell from your code whether you've done this or not, but I would also suggest breaking out your imports for the Material Modules into its own file, like above, and import/export the separate module in your app.module.ts. For the sake of "only import the portions you will use to optimize build", you can delete whichever modules you do not use in your app from the imports and const exports.